# How Parsley PropertiesFile can be reloded, avoiding the cached version is loaded?

Tags: caching, flex4, configuration-files, http-caching, parsley

In an old `Flex 4.1` project I'm using `Parsley 2.3.0` and it is configured by a `PropertiesFile` tag in my main `mxml` file, as follow:

```
<parsley:ContextBuilder>
    <parsley:PropertiesFile file="parsley.properties" />
</parsley:ContextBuilder>
```

The problem is that now I've added a new property in the properties file, but the cached version of the file is always loaded by customers' browsers, and then the new property is lost.
Apart from cleaning the browser cache (a solution the customers have already discarded also for the SWF file) is there a suggestion that you have about it?

I've googled a lot finding several solution about how SWF caching can be avoided, but nothing on `Parsley` configuration reloading.

Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can configure your web server to avoid caching for that specific file? Not sure though.

Comment: Any solutions you find about browser caching problems should apply. There is nothing specific about the parsley properties file w/respect to it being cached by the browser. Simply changing the name of the file would fix the issue, right? Granted that's an unsophisticated solution, there are plenty of other solutions out there w/varying levels of sophistication.